# In high enough pressure shit becomes a diamond

Tags: idiom

I have this proverb I use quite commonly. I was wondering what it would be in latin. Can you help me?

*"In high enough pressure even shit becomes a diamond."

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is it important that you have literally "shit" and "diamond", or is it enough if the overall message is the same?

Comment: Yeah. It is important to keep diamond and shit in this case. : P

Answer (score 2):

> *pressura satis magna coactum fit stercus adamas.*
>
> (If) Compressed by sufficiently great pressure, shit becomes a diamond.

*pressura*: The *Oxford Latin dictionary* defines this as 'The action or fact of pressing, pressure'; it's used of the force of water and the crush of a crowd. It's also used to describe pressing things such as grapes.

*coactum*: A form of the verb *cogere*, which has as one definition, 'To compress; to form into by compression; also, to bring (to a new condition) by pressure.' Pliny the Elder uses it in the context of gemstones in *Naturalis historia* 37.1, where he speaks of the 'grandeur of the universe densely compressed' (*in artum coacta rerum naturae maiestas*).

If you want something slightly pithier, you could omit *coactum* without impairing the meaning.

Comment: Nice find with *cogere*! But does *stercus* really capture the meaning of "shit" in English? To my understanding *stercus* isn't inherently negative, more like English "manure".

Comment: @Draconis. I was taking stercus as inherently unsavory and relying on the juxtaposition of stercus and adamas to do a lot of the heavy lifting. Were you thinking *coacta...merda* maybe?

Comment: Perhaps? I don't honestly know of a better word for this, I just have a vague recollection of excrement-related words not being particularly taboo.

Comment: Thanks. My life is complete.

Comment: @Galbathor Once you've got the answer you were looking for, you can tick the little green checkmark to the top left of the answer. That marks the answer as accepted. It gives a little reward to the answerer and signals that you've found what you wanted. (After getting 15 reputation points, you can also vote up any questions and answers you like.)